# The usage of relative pronoun 'that'

Tags: grammar

Which of these is correct? or both are correct?

a) I live in the house that my friend sold to me.
b) I live in the house my friend sold to me.

Is it ungrammatical to **not** put 'that' in the sentence?

Or are there certain rules explaining about when we should and shouldn't put the relative pronoun 'that'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a rule:

> A relative pronoun is optional when the relative clause has a non-subject gap.

Every *that*-relative clause has a gap, a *missing constituent* that's linked to the modified noun phrase. The gap may be in the subject position:

> I want a house<sub>i</sub> [that ___<sub>i</sub> is big and beautiful] (subject gap)

Note that the subject in the relative clause is missing, but it's anaphorically linked to the noun "house". When the gap is in the subject position, **the relative pronoun is obligatory**, at least in the standard English; hence, the ungrammatical sentence below:

> *I want a house is big and beautiful

When the gap is *not* in the subject position (eg. the object position or the prepositional-complement position), the relative pronoun is optional:

> I live in the house<sub>i</sub> [(that) my friend sold _____<sub>i</sub> to me] (object gap)

Since the missing constituent in the relative clause is the direct object of the verb "sold", the omission of the relative pronoun won't make the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: I think that's a misleading way of putting things. Not every relative clause has a 'gap'. For example in "This is the DVD [which is defective]", "which" is in its 'correct' position, as subject of the relative clause, so there is no gap. Also, "that" is part of the relative clause and hence should be enclosed in the brackets: "I want a house [that is big and beautiful].

Comment: @BillJ I understand your position, but it took me a few weeks to fathom  CGEL's analysis of relative clause and that would be too much for the OP, who doesn't seem to understand how a relative clause works. I believe this oversimplified cut-and-dried rule, although innacurate, would be helpful for the OP. Btw, I think it would be a good idea that you post your own answer; that would offer a different insight which will help the OP understand better.

Comment: I know what you mean! It would be clearer to say "Every _that_ relative clause has a gap", which is of course true.

Comment: @BillJ I have edited the answer.